# How to pass a page content to another page and then save it into Mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a button code with JavaScript. This button works as a file upload button. When user click on this button a file browser window will be open and user select a file to upload. After selecting the file the page automatically redirect to another page.

**PROBLEM:**

I want to pass the content of my button (File which is upload by the user using button) to the another page while redirection on other page. and then save it into Mysql Db.

Here is my button code:

**a1.php**

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script>
            function setup() {
                document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);
                function openDialog() {
                    document.getElementById('fileid').click();
                }
                document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
                function submitForm() {
                    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body onLoad="setup()">
        <form id='formid' action="mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input id='fileid' type='file' name='filename' hidden/>
            <input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' /> 
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' hidden="" /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Code on which user redirect after uploading file

**mb.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

//$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra-daily";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//$id2 = $_GET['id'];

$sql="SELECT pacra_teams.title as 'teamTitle', og_users.display_name, og_users.id
FROM og_users
LEFT JOIN pacra_teams
ON pacra_teams.id = og_users.team_id
Where og_users.id = 20 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Upload Morning Briefing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script> 
</head>
<body>

 <form action="up_mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="margin:auto; width:auto" align="center">
   <table width="547" class="tblbdr" >
    <tr>
        <td height="23"  colspan="6" class="head"><p>  Morning Briefing </p></td>
</tr>
 <tr> <td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Date:</b> </td> <td><input name="mydate" type="text" id="mydate" style="width:300px" readonly> </td></tr>
<tr>

<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Title: </b><br> </td> 

<td class="celltext" style="width:200px" >  <span id="dt_title"> <input name="title" type="text" value=" MB | 
<?php echo $row->teamTitle;?> | <?php echo $row->display_name; ?> | <?php echo date("d-M-y");?>" 
data-title="MB | <?php echo $row->teamTitle;?> | <?php echo $row->display_name;?> | " style="width:300px"/ readonly> </span> </td> </tr>
</tr>
<td class="celltext"><b>Upload File:</b></td>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" width="100%" size=80/>

   <!-- <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple style="width:300px"/> -->
   </td></tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/> </td> <td> </td>
    <td width="151">

   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="12">
    </td>
    <td width="290">

   </td> </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In `mb.php` i want to replace my following code

```
<td class="celltext"><b>Upload File:</b>
</td>
<td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" width="100%" size=80/>

    <!-- <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple style="width:300px"/> -->
</td>
</tr>
```

With the content of button. And then i want to store it in db.

How I can Pass the content of a page?

Comment: Do you want to replace the following code when uploading file? What do you mean with "the content of button"?

Comment: @Tobias On starting of my question i talk about  a button which upload a file then it redirect on `mb.php` here i want to pass the button content

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are starting a session in php. You can use session variables to carry over variables from one page to another as long as they are in the same session.
eg: `$_SESSION["filename"]=$_POST["filename"];` in a1.php to store your filename.
(You can fetch the value through $_POST for your button)

Then in m2.php you can retrieve the same by using `$_SESSION["filename"]`

Make sure you have `session_start()` in the pages you need this value.

Here's the reference for sessions in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Pandey how i can store my value in session?

Comment: For example you want to save your name in a session variable user $_SESSION[user]="Saqib";

Comment: Pandey i cannot use hard code here. User upload file with his choice.

Comment: Yeah , that was just an example. $_SESSION[filename]=$_POST["fileid"]; to save.

Comment: My bad , then it should be $_SESSION[filename]=$_POST["filename"] since your input element's name is filename.

Comment: I did it same with `$_SESSION[filename]=$_POST["filename"]` its not working

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php

session_start();

//$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra-daily";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//$id2 = $_GET['id'];

$sql="SELECT pacra_teams.title as 'teamTitle', og_users.display_name, og_users.id
FROM og_users
LEFT JOIN pacra_teams
ON pacra_teams.id = og_users.team_id
Where og_users.id = 20 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Here you can put your code when clicking the button
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Upload Morning Briefing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
   function setup() {
                document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);
                function openDialog() {
                    document.getElementById('fileid').click();
                }
                document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
                function submitForm() {
                    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
                }
            }
</script> 
</head>
<body>

 <form action="up_mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="margin:auto; width:auto" align="center">
   <table width="547" class="tblbdr" >
    <tr>
        <td height="23"  colspan="6" class="head"><p>  Morning Briefing </p></td>
</tr>
 <tr> <td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Date:</b> </td> <td><input name="mydate" type="text" id="mydate" style="width:300px" readonly> </td></tr>
<tr>

<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Title: </b><br> </td> 

<td class="celltext" style="width:200px" >  <span id="dt_title"> <input name="title" type="text" value=" MB | 
<?php echo $row->teamTitle;?> | <?php echo $row->display_name; ?> | <?php echo date("d-M-y");?>" 
data-title="MB | <?php echo $row->teamTitle;?> | <?php echo $row->display_name;?> | " style="width:300px"/ readonly> </span> </td> </tr>
</tr>
<td class="celltext"><b>Upload File:</b></td>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  
      <form id='formid' action="mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input id='fileid' type='file' name='filename' hidden/>
            <input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' /> 
            <input type='submit' name="submit" value='Submit' hidden="" /> 
        </form> 
   </td></tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/> </td> <td> </td>
    <td width="151">

   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="12">
    </td>
    <td width="290">

   </td> </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to replace the contect of my button which is uploaded by the user

Comment: the content of your button which is uploaded by the user... okay